# fix scale of multiple hist in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, histogram

hi
I have a MATLAB program in which I draw several histograms. each time the hist is re-scaled (the axes). I want all of the hists to be shown at the same scale.
this is the program:

```
clc  
close all  
PopSize=10^3;  
SampleSize=1:100:PopSize;  
NumberOfSamples=10^2;  
Pop=randn(PopSize);  
figure(NumberOfSamples+1);  
hist(Pop);  
sample=[];
for j=1:100:PopSize  
for i=1:1:NumberOfSamples  
    Pop=SHUFFLE(Pop);  
    sample(i)=mean(Pop(1:j));  
end  
figure(i+j);  
hist(sample);  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want all `hist` calls to use the same counting intervals ('bins' or 'buckets'), use:

```
hist(Y,x)
```

Where `x` is a vector of bin centers. You can also use `histc` if you want to specify bin edges instead of centers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code modification:

```
%# ...
h = [];
for j=1:100:PopSize
    %# ...
    h(end+1) = gca;                        %# get handle to histogram axis
end

mx = max( cellfun(@max,get(h,'YLim')) );   %# get the max count of all histograms
set(h, 'YLim',[0 mx])                      %# set the y-limit of all axes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AXIS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axis.html) command to both get and set the axis limits.  For instance, after your first plot you could do `axvals = axis();`, and after each subsequent plot do `axis(axvals);` to set all the plots to the same limits as the first one.